# Cloned button does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascript / jquery to clone a table with some input files and a button. After cloning the button doesn't seem to work anymore when it has the same class.

The situation:
When you click the add product, a row will be copied under the last row, so that a user can add an other product to the option. Here's an example:
[image]
[image]

There's an other button beneath those products: Create option. This button clones the first table (Option) and past it under the button. But after it has been copied, the button 'Add Product' doesnt seem to work anymore
[image]

I don't have any errors, so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is the code that I'm using to clone the tables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addproduct').click(function (e) {
        // Clone a product and add it to the option.
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = document.getElementById('hiddenTemplate').cloneNode(true);
        $('#hiddenTemplate').before(item);
        $(item).removeAttr('id');

    });
    $('.addOption').click(function (e){
        // Create a new option
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = document.getElementById('hiddenOption').cloneNode(true);
        $('.newOption').append(item);
        $(item).removeAttr('id');
        $(item).addClass('tableOptions');
    });
});
```

Could some1 explain to me what I'm doing and what might be an solution? My code isn't prefect atm i think and I'm open for learning!

Happy Coding!

Comment: `cloneNode()` does not copy event handlers. I'd suggest using jQuery's `clone(true)` instead, which does, or using delegated event handlers. The latter would be the easiest.

Comment: Whenever you generate dynamic html, the events are not bounded to them because all events are bounded before a webpage is generated. So delegation of events is required i.e. adding events to the parent element. Check @Ameya Deshpande answer.

Comment: Does the 'Create option' button re-use the `.addproduct` click code? If not, it would help if you posted it as well as the associated HTML

Answer (score 1):

use `document.on` when you add elements dynamically to DOM

```
 $(document).on('.addproduct','click', function (e) {
        // Clone a product and add it to the option.
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = document.getElementById('hiddenTemplate').cloneNode(true);
        $('#hiddenTemplate').before(item);
        $(item).removeAttr('id');

    });

    $(document).on('.addOption','click',function (e){
        // Create a new option
        e.preventDefault();
        var item = document.getElementById('hiddenOption').cloneNode(true);
        $('.newOption').append(item);
        $(item).removeAttr('id');
        $(item).addClass('tableOptions');
    });
```

Comment: When i use your code, the 'hiddenOption' doesn't get cloned anymore.

Comment: did you debug it ?

Comment: Jep, there are no errors + if i look in the code there is no new tr

Comment: .clone(true) seems to work tho, but idk why your solution didn't work.

Comment: did it get into the click event  ?